# Issues with c++ cast overloading operator

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading

I have a templated class which has a cast operator defined on it. This does not seem to work as expected when I define a stand alone overload for `operator+`.

```
template <class TT>
class Mtx
{
private:
    MtxView<TT> m_view;
public:
    operator const MtxView<TT> &() const { return m_view; }
    operator MtxView<TT>() { return m_view; }
    ...
};

template <class TT> Mtx<TT> operator+(const MtxView<TT> &m1, const MtxView<TT> &m2) 
{...}
```

In my test code below I get a compile error for the use of '+' which is "Invalid operands to binary expression." I would have expected that the cast operator would allow this to work. Why is this failing and how can I fix it (without subclassing from `MtxView`)?

```
Mtx<float> m1, m2, m3;
...
m1 = m2 + m3;
```

Comment: Have you defined an overload for operator= in your Mtx class to take an argument of type MtxView (assuming operator+ returns an MtxView)?

Comment: As defined above, `operator+` returns a `Mtx` not a `MtxView`.

Comment: Your operator+ is a template. When deducing argument types, function templates require an exact match. User-defined conversions are never considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

g++ gives better error messages (OT: probably the first time anyone's ever said that)

```
e.cc:22:10: note: candidate is:
e.cc:16:29: note: template<class TT> Mtx<TT> operator+(const MtxView<TT>&, const MtxView<TT>&)
     template <class TT> Mtx<TT> operator+(const MtxView<TT> &m1, const MtxView<TT> &m2)
                         ^
e.cc:16:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
e.cc:22:12: note:   'Mtx<float>' is not derived from 'const MtxView<TT>'

m1 = m2 + m3;
          ^
```

The template deduction fails because of 14.8.1/6:

> Implicit conversions (Clause 4) will be performed on a function argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function parameter if the parameter type contains no template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction

In plain language this says that implicit conversion operators are not considered when performing deduction of the parameter `TT` for a function template `template<typename TT> U operator+(`...

So the compiler cannot deduce what type `TT` should be.

[MM's solution](http://codepad.org/SbpNckOF) (now deleted) works because `operator+` there is not a function template; `TT` is already known by virtue of the fact that you are calling a member function of a `Mtx<float>`.

Comment: +1 I couldn't explain it as clear as yours. He needs to explicitly declare operators for those types.

Comment: OK this is good. I actually just tested it on a version without templates and it compiled ok.

Comment: However, the whole point of doing it like that was to avoid adding the operator on either Mtx or MtxView for a number of reasons.

Comment: There's probably a design pattern for fixing this without having to explicitly list every type you are going to use it with

Comment: `MtxView` could be made a public base of `Mtx` .. or else you could also define `template <class TT> Mtx<TT> operator+(const Mtx<TT> &m1, const Mtx<TT> &m2)` which could explicitly call the other `operator+`

Comment: These are good suggestions. However there are a number of objects, not just `Mtx` that make use of `MtxView` and they are supposed to be light weight, where `MtxView` is generated on the fly if needed, so deriving them from `MtxView` adds a whole bunch of storage. I wanted to define addition once and have it work for all the objects that can be converted to `MtxView`. Putting addition on `MtxView` is not really possible because `MtxView` cannot make use of the `Mtx` class as a return type, in part because `Mtx` only works for a sub set of types that are supported by `MtxView`.

Comment: Deriving from `X` uses no more storage than having an `X` as a member variable (unless perhaps `X` uses no storage)